# How to split expressJS server code into different files

Tags: javascript, express

This is just a part of my express server. I would like to split the code to different files.

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.get('/import', async (req, res) => {
  var fs = require('fs')

  fs.createReadStream('./src/data.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
      delimiter: ',',
      skip_lines_with_error: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
    .on('data', async function (row) {
      // do a lot of stuff here
    })

  res.status(200)
})
```

In this case the *import* should be imported from another file, but I don't know how to do that.

**helper/import.js**

```
export const import = (req, res) => {
  var fs = require('fs')

  fs.createReadStream('./src/data.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
      delimiter: ',',
      skip_lines_with_error: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
    .on('data', async function (row) {
      // do a lot of stuff here
    })

  res.status(200)
}
```

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.get('/import') // <-- ??
```

How do I get the async function here?

Comment: I think something like this: `var importRouter = require('./import'); app.use('/import', importRouter);`

Comment: by the way, espress generator https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html gives you a nice bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to put routes in a different file.

I tend to create a folder with all my 'routes' in.

Let's use import.js as an example.. here's what the file would look like:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var fs = require('fs')

  fs.createReadStream('./src/data.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
      delimiter: ',',
      skip_lines_with_error: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
    .on('data', async function (row) {
      // do a lot of stuff here
    })

  res.status(200)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Your server.js would then implement that...

```
const importRouter = require("./helper/import.js");

app.use('/import', importRouter);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app.use('/import', importRouter)` in the server.js file?

Comment: @user3142695 Sorry, you're right. I did it other way round.

Comment: But if I export the `get` function, I don't know how to write a unit test for that.

Comment: @user3142695 That was not part of your question. If you define routing, then /import will run the given path in the router. No idea about what framework you're using but it might be a good idea to ask another question specifically about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use router in order to do this, here is a simpler version, hope it helps.

**import.js**

```
const import = (req, res) => {
  //...
};

module.exports = {import};
```

**server.js**

```
const {import} = require('./import.js');

app.get('/import', import);
```